# Como mostrar lo que se ingreso en un formulario HTML a traves de jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, formularios, class

Tengo un problema en el cual los datos que se llenan en un formulario, con jquery no se pueden visualizar en pantalla.

**El error que aparece es este cuando se completa el formulario:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como puedo hacer para mostrar con jquery lo que se ingreso en el form con un append y mostrarlos con el this de la clase que esta declarada al principio? Hay forma mas facil de realizarlo?

```
class Persona {
  constructor(nombre, apellido, email, tel, cons, hora, dia) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.email = email;
    this.tel = tel;
    this.cons = cons;
    this.hora = hora;
    this.dia = dia;
  }
}
$("#data").append(`<h1> Datos del solicitante de turno: </h1>
                                <p> Nombre y apellido: ${this.nombre} ${this.apellido} </p>
                                <p> Email: ${this.email} </p>
                                <p> Numero de telefono: ${this.tel} </p>
                                </br>
              `);

<form id="formulario" method="POST" action="#">
                  <label for="nombre">Nombres<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                  <input id="nombre" type="text" name="Nombre del paciente" class="form-control" required
                    placeholder="Nombres" />
                  <label for="apellido">Apellido<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                  <input id="apellido" type="text" name="Apellido del paciente" class="form-control" required placeholder="Apellido" />
                  <label for="email">Correo electrónico<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                  <input id="email" type="email" name="Email del paciente" class="form-control" required placeholder="ejemplo@correo.com.ar" />
                    <label for="tel">Numero de telefono<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                  <input id="tel" type="number" name="Numero de telefono del paciente" class="form-control" required placeholder="+341 1234567"/>
                  <label class="mb-2" for="cons">Consultorio</label>
                  <select id="cons" name="Consultorio" class="form-control mb-2" required>
                    <option> Seleccione consultorio </option>
                    <option value="SP">SP</option>
                    <option value="WP">WP</option>
                  </select>
                  <label class="mb-2" for="dia">Dia</label>
                  <select id="dia" name="Dia del turno" class="form-control mb-2" required>
                    <option> Seleccione dia </option>
                    <option value="Lunes">Lunes</option>
                    <option value="Martes">Martes</option>
                    <option value="Miercoles">Miercoles</option>
                    <option value="Jueves">Jueves</option>
                    <option value="Viernes">Viernes</option>
                  </select>
                  <label class="mb-2" for="hora">Hora</label>
                  <select id="hora" name="Hora del turno" class="form-control mb-2" required>
                    <option> Seleccione hora </option>
                    <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
                    <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                  </select>
                  <label for="comentario">Comentario<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                  <textarea id="comentario" name="Comentario/observacion" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Comentario"></textarea>
                  <button id="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block mb-5 mt-3">Enviar</button>
</form>

<div id="data"></div>
```

Comment: te está devolviendo objetos [HTMLInputElements](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) con añadir `.value` deberia mostrartelo, es javascript no jquery

Comment: Ya lo pude demostrar con un getElementById y con el value indicando el contenido del id de cada dato del formulario. Mi pregunta va igual como puedo hacer para mostrar esos datos con jquery

Comment: `$('#IdDelElemento').val("StringQueDeseasMostrar")` , `$('#IdDelElemento').append(html)` ó `$('#IdDelElemento').Html(html)`

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución sería invocar la clase **Persona** con los argumentos, estos argumentos deben ser recogidos desde el formulario con el **evento submit**.

Aquí te muestro como hacer esto:

```
$(function(){

    class Persona {
        constructor(nombre, apellido, email, tel, cons, hora, dia) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.apellido = apellido;
            this.email = email;
            this.tel = tel;
            this.cons = cons;
            this.hora = hora;
            this.dia = dia;
        }
    }
    
    window.Persona = Persona; //La clase sería global.
    
    $("#formulario").submit(function(et){
        
        //Prevencion del submit.
        
        et.preventDefault();
        et.stopPropagation();
        
        //Veo que con el HTML haces la validacion, por lo cual evito usar validaciones aqui, pero si las quieres en JS me avisas!
        
        let elementos = $("#formulario").children("input, select, textarea");
        
        let persona = new Persona($($(elementos)[0]).val(), $($(elementos)[1]).val(), $($(elementos)[2]).val(), $($(elementos)[3]).val(), $($(elementos)[4]).val(), $($(elementos)[5]).val(), $($(elementos)[6]).val(), $($(elementos)[7]).val());
        
        //Como estas usando el html en crudo, pues es preferible usar un html en vez del append, pero te funcionaría igual así que si quieres seguir usandolo, usalo.
        
        $("#data").html(`<h1> Datos del solicitante de turno: </h1>
                                    <p> Nombre y apellido: ${persona.nombre} ${persona.apellido} </p>
                                    <p> Email: ${persona.email} </p>
                                    <p> Numero de telefono: ${persona.tel} </p>
                                    </br>`); //Puedes poner más datos por aqui.
            
        });
});
```